# error while committing to gemstone respository : ZnHttpUnsuccessful : 501 Not Implemented

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, monticello

while adding my project to ss3.gemstone.com/ss but when I do commit in monticello I get following error "ZnHttpUnsuccessful : 501 Not Implemented"

Comment: Can you include from which Smalltalk (Pharo, Squeak, Gemstone,...) you are trying to upload. Also: include the full definition of the repository in monticello (the text you see when selecting 'edit repository)

Comment: I tried in pharo 1.4 we are using it for coursework. also the repo info is
 MCGemstoneRepository
location: 'http://ss3.gemstone.com/ss/'
user: '**'
password: '***'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the repository where you want to push to in your url. Your url points to the squeaksource base url, which is not valid.

For example:

```
MCGemstoneRepository
    location: 'http://ss3.gemstone.com/ss/MyProject'
    user: ''
    password: ''
```

Comment: thanks a lot. it works !!!<br/>
@Johan B :  could you please take a look here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004435/seaside-2-events-on-html-anchor