# seaside : 2 events on html anchor

Tags: smalltalk, seaside

In seaside I need to do two events - callback and go to the other url (google.com) on clicking a link but I am not able to do both of them. What could be possibly wrong here? Is there any way I can do both the events?

```
html anchor
    newTarget url: 'www.google.com';
    callback: [Transcript show: 'clicked on google.com'];
    with: ('www.google.com') .
```

Answer (score 4):

Because >>callback: and >>url: both update the href attribute on an Anchor tag, you can't use both on the same anchor. You will have to solve this by writing a callback method which executes your logic, and then uses javascript to open the page in a new window.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the default click behaviour of an anchor to accomplish this.
The code snippet below demonstrates how to do this with an ajax call that executes your action in a callback and sets the navigation to the other url as the ajax 'oncomplete' action.

```
html anchor
   url: 'javascript:{}';
   onClick: (html jQuery ajax 
                        callback: [ ... ];
                        onComplete:(html javascript goto:'http://www.google.com'));
    with: 'http://www.google.com'.
```

The snippet cancels the default click action on the anchor using the 'javascript:{}' code as the url. In some cases, I have also seen the use of '#' but in my experience that also scrolls your browser to the top. Next, it sets its proper 'click' handler that launches an ajax request, as I described before.

Comment: I tried using the above code and for callback I had a Transcript show but it does not work.

html anchor
   url: 'javascript:{}';
   onClick: (html jQuery ajax 
                        callback: [ Transcript show: 'Hello'. ];
                        onComplete:(html javascript goto:'www.google.com'));
    with: 'www.google.com'.

Comment: Okay... you need to add http:// to the url otherwise the browser takes it as a relative url

Comment: I tried it with http but still did not worked. When  i try to paste my code it its removing the http. 

html anchor
    url: 'javascript:{}';
    onClick: (html jQuery ajax 
                        callback: [ Transcript show: 'Clicked Google'. ];
                        onComplete:(html javascript goto:'http://www.google.com'));
     with: 'http://www.google.com'.