# Open a link in seaside using javascript

Tags: javascript, smalltalk, seaside

Hi I am a newbie in Seaside and Smalltalk. I am developing a search application where the user posts a query and the system displays relevant results. Now to implement feedback, I want to know when a user has clicked a particular link. Thus clicking on a link involves 2 things: 1) Navigating to that particular link 2) Registering in the background that the user has clicked that link. I am stuck at doing this. It would be great if someone could help out with this. I got some idea about how to go about doing this reading other posts where I was suggested to implement a callback and use javascript in that callback to open the link. Can some one provide the code for doing that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what kind of *link* you have. Is it a link to an (external) webpage or is it a link within the Seaside application itself? In case of the former, it would make sense to combine a Seaside callback for the click registration and javascript to navigate to the link. You can find an example for that in this question: [seaside : 2 events on html anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004435/seaside-2-events-on-html-anchor).

In the other case, the callback that executes when you click a link in a Seaside application can do both the registration of the user action and navigate the user to the other page in your application:

```
html anchor
   callback:[ self registerClick. self call:: newPageComponent];
   with: 'click this'
```

Check out the [Seaside book](http://book.seaside.st) to know all about callbacks and component navigation.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I had already tried doing that before posting the question here. Din't work for me.

Comment: my mistake... I did an #answer: instead of a #call:

Comment: I am trying to link to an external webpage. As you have mentioned, we can use javascript to navigate to the link. Can you post an example on how we can do that? I tried using the onComplete: method that you sugggested in that post. But it did not work.